# [r][plotly] How to couple a heatmap to a datatable, in order to display the row data for a selected tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2, datatable, plotly, bioinformatics

I made a heatmap of differential gene expression between subclusters of cells  from a data.frame `diffexp`, using `ggplot` and `ggplotly()`.

[image]

Every tile represents the number of genes that are differentially expressed between a pair of subclusters (shown as `total` in the tooltip).

```
cluster.heatmap <- 
  ggplot(diffexp) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = cluster_A, y = cluster_B, fill = total, 
    text = paste0("up_genes: ", up_genes)), 
    colour="white", size=0.05) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(begin=0.1, na.value="grey20") +
  ggtitle("Differentially Expressed Genes Between Subcluster Pairs")

ggplotly(cluster.heatmap)
```

I added the column which contains the list of `up_genes` to the tooltip via the

`text = paste0("up_genes: ", up_genes)` line.

Columns `diffexp$up_genes`, `diffexp$down_genes` contain the actual lists of genes.

However, as you can see in the image, in most cases this gene list is rather large and does not fit in the tooltip.

Therefore, I think the best solution is to have a coupled `datatable` which shows the list of genes, similar to what is shown here:

https://plot.ly/r/datatable/

[image]

This coupled table would show the dataframe row for the pair of `cluster_A` and `cluster_B` tile selected.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Dataframe `diffexp` looks like this:

```
dput(diffexp.results.full %>% head)

structure(list(cluster_A = c("cluster_1", "cluster_1", "cluster_1", 
"cluster_1", "cluster_1", "cluster_1"), cluster_B = c("cluster_1", 
"cluster_2", "cluster_3", "cluster_4", "cluster_5", "cluster_6"
), up = c(NA, 2, 4, NA, 50, NA), down = c(NA, 605, 14, 785, 754, 
14), total = c(NA, 607, 18, 785, 804, 14), up_genes = c(NA, "HBA2;HBG2", 
"GPR22;PCDH9;NEFL;NPY", NA, "MEF2C;DOK5;NEUROD6;STMN4;GAP43;EEF1B2;SATB2;LIMCH1;ACAT2;GPR22;FAM49A;ADCY1;RUNX1T1;MT-ND4L;PCLO;GRIN2B;NKAIN2;MPPED1;NEFM;DAB1;FGF12;R3HDM1;MSRA;CHL1;CHD5;NPY;NELL2;ARPP21;FAT3;NEFL;FLRT2;INA;LRRN3;HMGCR;TCTEX1D2;ATP2B1;CHCHD6;NTRK3;ACOT7;CAMKV;RP11-356J5.12;ADRA2A;SNCA;EBP;ARL2;SCN3B;C10orf35;GPR85;ITGAE;THY1", 
NA), down_genes = c(NA, "ARID4A;HIVEP2;MRFAP1;RNF11;CCSAP;CFAP36;FARP1;EFNA5;PKIG;DAAM1;GPR162;TANC2;GSK3B;KRAS;TMEM246;SRRM2;EPN2;WDR60;NIN;CAMTA1;DDT;MTDH;KMT2E;PFN2;TMEM35;TRIM37;ARID4B;NMNAT2;FAM177A1;ADGRL1;ATP1B3;CHGA;CEND1;ARPC5L;FGD5-AS1;TPM1;TCTEX1D2;MTX2;PSAP;PREPL;LINC00969;RSRP1;NAV3;C8orf34;SSB;MAP6;H2AFY2;RFPL1S;RAB14;CCSER2;MIAT;DISP2;RNF7;MRPL34;STUB1;SERINC3;CCNL2;RAB18;TAOK3;TAF9;DRAXIN;KLHL14;MKRN1;STX6;NPDC1;CEP170;GRB2;CCDC112;PCDH11Y;WNK3;SELM;VTI1B;GTF3A;FAM217B;COPS8;UBE2E2;ANKRD46;PRRC2C;NLRP1;FGF14;MRPL41;ATP1A3;PEG3;MAPRE2;RAB11A;STXBP1;NKTR;SV2A;ANKRD12;UBE3A;SNX3;GPRIN3;C9orf16;RAB6B;DDX17;SYP;PPIG;BMPR2;SLC38A1;PAFAH1B1;ATP8A2;TPM3;KIF1B;NFIX;ERC1;PPP2CA;KIAA1109;B3GALT2;GABRG2;DZIP3;HLTF;TARBP1;NDN;GLTSCR2;DYNC1H1;ACSL3;SLC25A3;YTHDC1;KLHL23;TSPAN7;BCL7A;PPM1K;PNISR;CAMK1D;CCDC85B;ROGDI;GNB4;RP11-382A20.3;KIF5B;SLF1;ACOT7;ARL8A;MAP1LC3B;TUBB4A;PRKCZ;WDR47;OPCML;CDC42BPA;UBXN4;TP53I11;MARCH6;REEP5;NDUFAB1;CDH8;SOCS2;G3BP2;RPAP2;CPEB4;DUT;ATP2B2;SSBP2;ADRBK2;KIT;RGMA;TSPAN13;DPF1;PCDH19;STMN3;RGS7;RALB;CMAS;CLCN3;NPY1R;EIF5;ARHGAP20;ZYG11B;DHX36;TENM2;SGIP1;LRP1B;HAGH;PRDM2;KAZN;SNRPN;COX5B;PAK3;ZMYND11;EID1;COMMD2;FAAP20;MTCH1;METTL9;TERF2IP;SNX10;JAKMIP2;APPL1;RIMS1;MAP1A;MOAP1;NUDT3;CKB;KIF3B;TNRC6C;HS3ST4;UBE2D2;ASH1L;ATRX;KALRN;TENM1;MLLT4;PAK2;RAB10;SHTN1;SATB1;GCSH;SH3GL2;CFAP97;KIFAP3;FZD3;ATP6V1A;MACF1;RAB3A;OCIAD1;RAB6A;CALY;ICK;MTSS1;ODF2L;KIAA2022;JTB;OPTN;SHISA9;ITM2B;GRM3;ALKBH7;PDZD2;PLK2;RABEP1;CXXC5;TNR;PCDH9;RIT2;NRXN2;TMEM59L;RCAN1;PPP3CA;LRRTM2;PYURF;SH3GL3;RTF1;PALM2;CAMSAP2;AURKAIP1;GSTM3;FXYD6;C19orf43;PCYOX1;SRSF11;UROS;CCDC184;TOMM20;MARCKS;LDHA;CNIH2;AC159540.1;RUNDC3B;ZC3H13;KIF21A;GNB1;MTUS1;PITHD1;ACBD6;PCM1;KAT6B;ASAH1;SRPK1;SLC25A36;C3orf14;TOX;FAM161A;ENOPH1;PRNP;GABBR2;ARL5A;CACNG8;GUCY1A3;EXOC6;ABI2;AFF3;BNIP3;PLEKHA5;TPR;CNRIP1;SET;ROBO2;VDAC1;BACH2;GABARAPL2;GABPB1-AS1;UGP2;SCN9A;TRPM3;ATPIF1;CELF2;NAV1;NCAM1;ATP5D;GADD45GIP1;MARCH1;GNG4;CALM3;APLP1;UBL3;AAK1;PLEKHB2;AKAP12;TNIK;NAP1L3;NTRK2;RAB7A;CACNA2D1;QDPR;MPC2;TIMP2;ACTR3B;CBLN2;ADCY1;PTPRA;ARL6IP5;TSPAN5;NBEA;RAB1A;LINC00657;PSIP1;PPM1G;DKK3;SMARCA2;SOX5;B3GAT1;MACROD2;ARF3;MRPS6;C5orf24;SESTD1;RUNX1T1;NAP1L5;SESN3;RERE;RBFOX1;FRRS1L;FAM171B;SUMO3;ARGLU1;SLC25A4;FAM155A;GRIK2;CLSTN2;GAS7;UQCRFS1;FAM213A;IDS;FKBP1A;TMEM14A;KIDINS220;NCOR1;TMOD2;AGAP1;MYT1L;HP1BP3;NUAK1;AHI1;KCNMA1;ARFGEF3;PEG10;NTRK3;CDKL2;TCEAL2;ATP6AP2;PWAR6;SPINT2;ISOC1;HPCA;CLTA;YWHAG;GUCY1A2;KCNQ1OT1;ZNF428;RUFY3;DNM3;CDKN2D;APC;RTN3;SLC8A1;NLGN1;TMEM160;MZT2A;CADM3;PGAM1;MDH1;POLE4;GNAQ;LAGE3;RALA;APLP2;PKIA;CADPS;PPM1L;NDRG4;KIF3A;ELAVL3;MTPN;CCDC88A;NFIB;VAPA;KLC1;PSD3;SULF2;PJA2;CAMKV;SOSTDC1;FEZF2;GABRB2;CTNND2;SEZ6L2;PGRMC1;PRKACB;ALCAM;ROBO1;INA;SH3BP5;CACNA1E;PODXL2;APP;FXYD7;DUSP23;IGSF21;PRKCB;SMAP1;GRM5;BDP1;ATP6V0E2;TBR1;HSPA12A;SERINC1;FABP3;PRKAR2B;YWHAQ;SRPK2;SH3GLB1;RHEB;NOVA1;MAP1LC3A;ELAVL4;MGAT4C;RAC3;FGF12;DCLK1;CSRNP3;CAMK2N1;KIF1A;ITM2C;GUK1;RFK;EIF1AX;CPE;THRA;CCDC144A;ATP6V0B;ARPC2;DST;GPR22;CXXC4;PEX5L;PHF14;LIMCH1;RGS17;CYP26A1;MYCBP2;CLTB;LRRC4C;TTLL7;ITSN1;SCG2;XKR4;CXADR;SNAP25;SPOCK1;C4orf48;XPR1;MGLL;NECAB1;NEGR1;FAM3C;SERPINI1;WHSC1L1;GNAO1;PCLO;CTNNBL1;TRIM2;SPTBN1;FOXP1;KHDRBS3;FAM49A;BEX5;ATP2B1;ELMOD1;CADM1;SNCA;FKBP1B;TUSC3;DYNC1I1;CD47;RSPO3;ZEB2;KIF5C;FSTL5;RAB2A;SCN3B;SARAF;ZNF385D;LY6H;MAPT;CADM2;AKAP7;CNTN1;SEMA3E;KCNJ6;TSHZ3;RIMS2;NRCAM;RALYL;CLSTN1;YWHAB;SOBP;COX5A;TTC9B;VSTM2L;LMO7;VSNL1;SCOC;SCN2A;YWHAH;LDB2;OLFM1;GNAL;PGM2L1;SCD5;WASF1;PBX1;GRIN2B;BCL11B;NRXN1;SYT6;PCDH10;PCSK1N;CHL1;NDFIP1;HMP19;BASP1;PDE1A;SYT1;CNTNAP2;SLN;RPRM;RBP1;VAMP2;TLE4;ATP1B1;GRIA2;ANK3;KCTD12;PCDH17;LSAMP;CELF4;ARPP21;NFIA;PPP1R1B;LMO4;SSTR2;FBXW7;PCP4;CRYM;LMO3;IGFBP5;MEG3;DDAH1;EPHB1;NCKAP5;TMEFF2;LYPD1;GRID2;ANK2;NYAP2;NUCKS1;THSD7A;BEX2;GRIK3;CYCS;MGST3;DPYSL3;ETV1;CLU;FABP6;SEZ6L;SYNPR;GRP;BCYRN1;CALB2;VCAN;TRH;NEFL;PTN;CCK;TAGLN2;LGALS1", 
"LMO3;SLN;VSTM2L;YWHAH;SRM;RPRM;NFIA;LINC01102;CACNA2D1;XIST;SCG2;MVD;LDB2;EXOC6", 
"MZT2B;EBPL;GLTSCR2;RNF11;RHEB;DUT;RAB14;METTL9;GUK1;PNCK;VSTM2B;CMIP;RAB6A;EIF1AX;UBE2S;SCAMP1;MTSS1;NPDC1;NAP1L5;CLTA;FXYD1;FZD3;CA10;APPL1;OSBPL8;CCDC184;LAGE3;UQCRFS1;GNG4;CCSER2;OSBPL1A;HSPH1;CD47;FEZ2;C1QBP;DUSP23;TMOD3;CNTNAP2;PHF14;MEF2A;TRIM37;PLPPR4;RAC1;NDN;CRIP2;DDX17;VAPA;CHRM3;NTRK2;MAPK10;GABRB1;APLP2;GSK3B;ANKRD36;COX5A;ZMYND11;AP1S2;PRKCB;TSPAN5;JAKMIP1;CMAS;GNB4;CCDC85B;PRR7;CNTN4;FSTL5;SEZ6L2;RAB7A;MTCH1;CDKN2D;GABBR2;GUCY1A3;DLG2;RAB3A;TARSL2;POLE4;YTHDC1;MMD;MTPN;ARHGAP20;SLBP;BIN1;KHDRBS3;RIT2;FGF14;PPM1G;JPH4;AKAP7;GRM7;GABRA2;CNRIP1;ARPC2;CDH13;NAP1L3;RUFY3;ATP5D;GADD45GIP1;ALCAM;LINC00643;RNF145;ELAVL4;KRAS;TUBB4A;EPN2;ATP6AP2;DYNC1H1;ITM2B;APP;SH3BP5;NEGR1;FARP1;CLCN3;RGS17;TMEM160;CALB1;SH3GL3;GRM5;NPY1R;MYEF2;CLTB;UBE2E2;PJA2;CDKL2;SMARCA2;KLHL23;CTXN1;CHGB;TNR;TSPAN7;OPTN;CFAP97;PTPRK;FKBP1B;STXBP1;RAB10;SYT5;FXYD7;MACROD2;RNF19A;HSPA1A;LINC00657;KIAA1109;ARL8A;NRCAM;KTN1;AASDHPPT;PVRL3;CELF2;RTF1;DEK;TPM3;TERF2IP;FAM49A;CADM1;CADM3;LMO7;THRA;EIF3J;SRGAP3;AHI1;APC;CLSTN1;TUSC3;DAAM1;KHDRBS2;PGRMC1;VDAC1;KCNJ6;AAK1;MARCH1;CCDC88A;NFIA;SCN3B;PAK2;PAFAH1B1;ROBO1;FABP3;MAP1LC3A;KIF21A;SMAP1;CGGBP1;TCEAL6;NCOR1;SYNE1;C5orf24;ERICH3;PODXL2;SERINC1;GRID2;DST;XKR4;LPL;CAMK2B;FGF12;RABEP1;PGM2L1;TRIM2;SRRM2;SCOC;HNRNPD;MIF;PRKAR2B;KIF2A;BCL7A;RALYL;TMEM59L;REEP1;CPE;SARAF;PRKACB;FAM3C;AGTPBP1;KIFAP3;RTN3;IGFBP5;SCN9A;SLC8A1;PSD3;ARGLU1;LDB2;OLFM1;ZEB2;TMOD2;CCK;SNCA;SSTR2;APLP1;CCDC112;KIF1A;WHSC1L1;R3HDM1;MYCBP2;TPM1;NRXN1;RALA;SCD5;RAB2A;WASF1;RAC3;PTPRA;PCDH10;CADM2;RFK;GRIA2;INA;HP1BP3;BDP1;YWHAB;NDFIP1;SPOCK1;SPTBN1;NLRP1;EXOC6;SEC62;CXXC4;TTLL7;LY6H;FOXP1;CBLN2;SYT1;GNAL;TTC9B;NECAB1;ATP2B1;MGAT4C;BEX5;GNAO1;VAMP2;CNTN1;PPFIBP1;DYNC1I1;RSPO3;SH3GLB1;MAPT;MARCKS;KIF5C;PEG10;VSTM2L;ELMOD1;LRRC4C;PCSK1N;CALY;PCLO;CHL1;SCN2A;PSIP1;GRIN2B;HMP19;ANK3;PCDH17;ENC1;C4orf48;GRP;CELF4;PIK3R1;RPRM;ATP1B1;YWHAH;RTN4;SLN;HIST1H4C;MEF2C;PKIA;CACNA2D1;FBXW7;BASP1;LSAMP;ARPP21;LMO3;SCG2;CALM1;LMO4;MEG3;SUDS3;CHD5;GCSH;FRRS1L;ZRANB2;RAB6B;GRB2;SNAP25;CCDC144A;SUMO3;EPHB6;MACF1;ABCA5;STUB1;ANK2;PRNP;PPP1R14C;SYBU;FBXO9;BHLHE22;C1QTNF4;RP11-382A20.3;KIF3B;HTATSF1;HPCA;UBL3;DCLK1;POLR2L;CDH8;SMARCA1;YPEL3;R3HDM2;SSBP2;PAK3;BNIP3;GNAQ;ATP1A3;HNRNPAB;GTF3A;FRZB;NOL7;ANKRD46;DENR;CXADR;CBX3;SEPT11;ELAVL3;KIF3A;ACSL3;DRAXIN;AFF3;KLC1;LZIC;SHTN1;KLF6;YWHAG;FAM171B;KIAA2022;AP1AR;KIF1B;NRXN2;DSEL;MLF2;PALM2;AP2B1;CLASP2;PGAM1;GUCY1B3;IDS;ZC3H13;VIMP;C19orf43;SYT4;PFN1;TJP1;ITSN1;NRP2;FAM161A;RAB4A;DHX36;ATPIF1;HIVEP2;THOC7;TMEFF2;CCSAP;RAP1GDS1;EIF5;DZIP3;PENK;KCNQ1OT1;RUFY2;PTMS;SESTD1;SOCS2;GABRB3;PHF20L1;PCM1;TSPAN13;PNMA1;CACNG3;STXBP6;CSRNP3;GABRA4;FEZ1;GRIA4;DEAF1;ZC3H6;TCEAL2;PTPN11;IGSF21;SNAP91;FAM81A;GNB2;JAK1;ARF3;KIAA1211;FGD5-AS1;SLF1;INAFM1;PBX1;RUNX1T1;PPP3CB;GSPT1;GRIK2;GABRG2;SACS;SLC25A36;KAT6B;CHN2;REEP5;AP2A2;UBE2K;PLK2;FGFBP3;TCEA1;YPEL1;SLC2A13;B3GALT2;SET;RAB1A;COPRS;USP14;FAM213A;THSD7A;FHL1;CPEB4;DTD1;PITHD1;RSRP1;ATP6V0B;XPR1;SCN3A;ACOT7;PYURF;ST8SIA3;PRRC2B;COMTD1;GNG2;ATP2B2;SLC25A4;PPM1K;CPNE8;CAMK1;SNX10;MYO16;WDR60;CSMD3;GDI1;FGF13;SLC22A17;ZNF302;C11orf87;SNRNP70;JAKMIP2;ARL6IP5;MAP6;CBX1;FBXO25;C1orf21;HAGH;CKB;MAPRE3;KIDINS220;RUNDC3B;ABI2;HLA-A;TOMM20;TM7SF2;ZNF428;SOSTDC1;NUDCD3;C14orf37;PPP2CA;DNM3;TMEM183A;PLPPR3;CAMK2N1;SRPK2;G3BP2;NELL2;MTDH;HOMER1;TAOK1;DKK3;L3MBTL3;PPP6R2;HNRNPU;KIAA0232;UBE3A;ACSL4;EPS8;MDGA1;GABARAPL2;COTL1;REV3L;SQLE;NARS;TPR;MYT1L;EIF2AK2;ARPC5L;ATAT1;SYNPR;NDRG4;NUCKS1;HERC2;CEP170;B3GNT2;CLMP;CAMSAP2;COX17;EIF2S2;ACTR3B;PDE4D;ZFAND5;BMPR2;EPHA5;DPP6;ERC1;FLRT3;TM9SF3;TSPAN3;PREPL;PPP2R2C;ZBTB38;CAMK1D;NPNT;C17orf89;SYNGR3;TNKS2;FRY;RIMS1;AC004158.3;CDC42EP3;CASC4;RDX;CACYBP;OLFM2;FAM19A1;KCNH5;FAM134B;GHITM;ARHGEF12;RP11-384F7.2;NUDT3;MAP7D2;NDUFA3;N4BP2;ADGRB3;NOL4;ZNF706;MIA3;CACNA1A;FAM50A;C18orf32;UBE2R2;ZCCHC11;TCAF1;TRIM44;AGGF1;ARL5A;UBXN4;TUBB4B;H1FX;CSNK1G3;RFPL1S;SLC39A10;LRRTM2;FBXW11;SSB;NTM;CCBE1;PPP2R2B;MICU1;SOBP;ZNF770;NRGN;KCNMA1;RASSF2;B4GAT1;MIAT;NCOA7;CFDP1;TANC2;SMCHD1;SPINT2;GPRIN3;GNPTAB;ANKRD12;CBX5;DNAJC15;CALB2;LDHA;KLHL14;SHOC2;SUPT16H;NAP1L4;STX1A;NDUFB1;MTURN;TENM1;VPS41;POLR2J3;PPP2CB;TNIK;MAP1A;WBP11;SPAST;BNIP3L;SYT11;MAN1A2;QDPR;ADGRL3;MPHOSPH8;ATP1B3;CCPG1;MPP6;ADCY1;CTDNEP1;SNCB;WAC-AS1;GULP1;RFX3;UBE2V1;DNM1L;RP11-286B14.1;PA2G4;TMEM35;RPRML;XIAP;EXOC1;RIMS2;ATP8A2;MAP9;SLAIN2;SYP;FSD1L;NBEA;NTRK3;PDE1A;GALNT2;SLCO3A1;CACNA1E;ANKRD36C;LINGO1;EHBP1;ICA1L;RASL10A;GNB1;ZFYVE9;AFG3L2;SCAPER;CSPG5;TMX4;DNAJC6;DPF1;DNAJB1;CDH10;S100A6;RP3-525N10.2;TPM4;PCYOX1;ATP8A1;HOOK3;TNRC6B;OCIAD1;TLN2;CLIP1;DNMT1;NAV3;OLA1;LRP1B;NCAM1;SLC38A1;FMNL2;UBE2E3;HEBP2;TAX1BP1;EFNB3;NAV2;FAM19A2;RHBDD2;MYO5A;GABPB1-AS1;CHMP2B;SRSF4;STX7;RAB11FIP2;GRIA1;LCORL;RAPGEF2;ATXN2;PDE4DIP;CADPS;MAPRE2;LUZP2;LARS;ZNF148;TAOK3;ERC2;UBE2H;ING2;HECTD1;SSX2IP;HSP90B1;CLCN4;PRRC2C;PTPRD;MIR137HG;ELOVL4;FNBP1L;EIF4G3;TMEM150C;NFIX;ANKRD36B;CCDC34;PLCG2;SHISA9;PCDH19;USP48;DYX1C1;ZDHHC21;IMMP1L;RSPH9;SERINC3;RORB;GOLGB1;SEPT6;PANK3;CEP290;RAD50;BCYRN1;SERPINI1;USP34;AC159540.1;SDC3;INPP4A;UGP2;NCOA1;HMGCR;ATP9A;WNK3;ATP1A1;PDIK1L;LRRN3;RPAP2;NR2F1;NEFL;PCSK2;PCDH9;CYB5D2;GPR22", 
"CENPV;PTMS;SEPP1;TERF2IP;PPP1R15A;NOS1AP;TMPO;ITGB1;CHD9;IER5;FUT9;TMEM123;MSI2;NPTX2;MLLT3;GOLIM4;PHF14;HMGN1;MAPK10;HMGB2;CCNL1;DCC;HIST1H1E;KCNQ3;SETD7;HP1BP3;TMEM158;RASGEF1B;GTF2I;SLC1A3;KDM1A;RDX;HNRNPU;RP11-76I14.1;SF1;POLR2J3;SRSF5;PTPRA;MTDH;PGAP1;HNRNPD;ITM2B;DEK;EPHB6;PAG1;PAX6;NEUROD1;AP1S2;YTHDC1;WSB1;UNC5D;JUND;BCLAF1;GABPB1-AS1;RCN2;NHLH1;MEX3A;CASC15;DDX17;FZD3;TFDP2;CLU;ELAVL4;KIF21A;HNRNPA0;NRP1;MPPED2;FBLN1;CLMP;HSPA1B;RP3-525N10.2;ARGLU1;RND3;APP;BICD1;MEG3;PNISR;SFPQ;CNR1;EZR;POU3F3;ELAVL2;RP11-553L6.5;RBPJ;B2M;GADD45G;DOK6;SOX2;ARL4C;FMNL2;PSIP1;BAZ2B;MDK;SFRP1;LRP8;SPAG9;ZEB1;WHSC1L1;KHDRBS1;PHLDA1;GRIA2;PPP2R2B;CALD1;NFIX;SRRM2;GLTSCR2;HSPB1;BTG3;FOSB;CCND2;DNAJB1;ENC1;MARCKS;ZNF704;NFIB;EOMES;NTM;H1FX;BTG2;IER2;RP11-436D23.1;MIR99AHG;CXXC5;BASP1;NRN1;CPE;SOX4;ROBO2;EGR1;CCNI;ZFHX4;PPP1R17;POU3F2;PNRC1;EMX2;HSPA1A;DUSP1;MEIS2;HES6;NFIA;SSTR2;JUN;BTG1;ZBTB20;SYNE2;FOS;MZT2B;CHD7;BBX;MEX3B;TSPAN5;PHYHIPL;JAK1;KLF3;SRSF9;RERE;FAM171B;INHBB;AC013461.1;ADGRV1;CHRDL1;PAK2;NKAIN3;TET1;MYEF2;CDKN1B;NCOR1;FYN;ZNF292;FSCN1;ARID4B;SMARCA5;TRIM9;RHOB;CBX1;PEG10;CORO1C;SNCAIP;NLRP1;SETBP1;HLA-C;SCRG1;SRSF4;HIST1H1C;QSER1;NES;PCM1;VGLL4;PRKX;ZNF83;PGRMC2;HLA-A;EBPL;SMOC1;KDM5B;IQGAP2;PALMD;RASGRP1;PTAR1;MXI1;SPECC1;MYO10;CCNG2;PBRM1;R3HDM2;PDCD7;FNBP1;HTRA1;TXNIP;EPC1;IRF2BPL;ARRDC3;DHRS7;COL9A2;SERP1;ILF3;RHOBTB3;ANP32B;FGFR2;MFAP2;CAMK2N1;PHIP;PODXL2;SRGAP3;CA12;MTUS1;ZNF711;EPHA5;APBA2;PCMTD1;SEPT11;ID4;SORBS2;ROCK1;ODC1;C19orf43;PRPF38B;VCAN;IGSF10;NFE2L2;SMARCB1;GPC2;SMARCC1;LINC00632;CLSTN1;TNRC6B;POU3F4;IGDCC3;MFGE8;PLCB1;KLHL35;KLHDC2;TARSL2;HIST1H1D;SYF2;FNBP4;DUSP4;TOB1;HPCAL1;RNF139;LHX2;FOXN3;CTSF;KLHL24;UBE3A;KAT6B;LGALS1;TMEM98;PALLD;SPIRE1;ATP5D;SRSF2;KIF5B;AFF4;CSNK1E;SCARB2;BAZ1A;TBR1;CNTNAP2;URI1;CCSER2;GABPB1;RALBP1;FRMD4B;IFRD1;SNHG7;UBE2S;PDE1C;PAXBP1;IFI44;GRIA3;SOX9;SLC17A6;POU2F1;SCAF11;INSM1;H1F0;FJX1;ST8SIA1;SEC63;EPHA3;UBE2D1;BOD1;DST;CHMP1B;LARP7;CNN3;EIF3F;RBM17;KCTD16;RSF1;EPC2;TPR;CTNNA1;TCEA1;SYNRG;SIAH2;DBN1;EPN2;CLK1;ANK3;ERBB2IP;NSD1;JMJD1C;AMER2;RBP1;FOXN2;CYP20A1;PTOV1;MUM1;MTF2;UBXN4;SNRNP70;NDN;SESN3;PPM1G;SPEN;ZNF274;ZNF821;KIAA1715;BAZ1B;ZNF804A;IDH2;NDFIP1;TSPAN3;CFAP97;C14orf37;PWWP2A;KCNN3;SCRN1;H2AFV;SCRT2;AKIRIN2;NFKBIA;STAT3;YTHDF2;LMNB1;MLLT4;SCAND1;MED17;CBFA2T2;ZNF638;LEPROT;ZHX1;IRF2BP2;PEA15;TPGS2;ROBO1;ATF7IP;AKR7A2;WAPL;PLCE1;USP1;RUFY2;PSAP;TBCC;NETO2;SYP;ST6GAL2;DUOX1;ARHGEF2;TSPYL2;SMARCD1;COPA;USP47;PPP1CC;GPM6B;PCBP2;RSBN1;UBA2;PNMA1;OSBPL8;ZKSCAN1;ELF2;SLC1A2;CCSAP;YY1;ZMIZ1;FANCF;C14orf132;TTC19;HLTF;TOPORS;QKI;UPF3A;HOOK3;ZCCHC11;CITED2;CMPK1;ABCD4;HERPUD1;KCTD6;NFIC;ANP32E;RAB4A;IFI27L2;CHD6;GOLM1;CALR;PRKAR1A;SEPT2;TMEM165;PLEKHA3;ZNF680;TRIM24;SMARCD3;BRD7;KMT2A;NCK1;CHD4;PKIA;FRMD4A;CALCOCO1;VCP;BSDC1;TOP1;DDX6;HUNK;SMCHD1;CAND1;ATP1B3;METTL9;GOLGA4;THOC2;SYT11;RGS2;NENF;TTLL7;SENP6;AAK1;PAFAH1B1;THSD7A;EXOC7;SEZ6;SH3BGRL;MOAP1;VEZF1;PAPOLA;FOXO3;ZNF131;VANGL2;LSAMP;NOVA1;ELP2;TMX1;HTATSF1;MKRN1;DHX36;SPATS2;ANKLE2;GSK3B;UBQLN2;KMT5B;PRRC2B;GLRX5;H2AFY;TPM4;ZFAND5;HS3ST1;EPM2AIP1;BLOC1S4;ARL5A;SECISBP2;HNRNPAB;KLHL28;STAG2;MSH6;MIDN;WASF2;SENP7;DOCK7;DNTTIP2;CPNE3;PLXNA2;YPEL3;LMO3;JADE1;GLCE;GRAMD1B;JUNB;DDX39B;HADHA;FBXO11;HSPA5;CSNK1G3;SMARCAD1;TMCO3;CDH2;CLCN3;ACAP2;UBL3;DPYSL4;FIP1L1;KAT6A;ADGRG1;CENPF;SPAST;CENPC;SETD5;PTTG1IP;ZNF43;CTBP2;MEST;ALDH7A1;CTNND1;ZBED1;PPP4R3A;CREBZF;ALDH3A2;SMARCC2;ERV3-1;FNIP1;CTCF;ATP6V0A1;MAF1;TMEM57;RRAGA;SMC5;PPP1R14B;GLG1;LINC00969;STARD4-AS1;LTA4H;TNRC6A;CLIP1;KRR1;THUMPD1;SLC25A36;PCMTD2;CDC42EP3;FBXO21;RAD23B;SRSF8;PPP6R2;ING3;TERF1;LSM14A;ICE1;SETD2;HNRNPUL1;EZH2;ZNF148;EHBP1;RAB8B;FAM215B;NUMA1;STX6;ACADM;TMEM106B;GBAS;SREK1;CDH11;RPS6KA5;APPL1;MAPK1IP1L;SFSWAP;EIF2AK2;STAG1;NF1;EPHB1;CDK12;ZNF397;MRPS30;CHD1;CCNL2;FHL1;FAM60A;PGRMC1;WNK1;RNF24;MCL1;BEND5;SGCB;USP3;MAGEF1;KTN1;EIF2AK1;HBP1;PDIA3;IMP3;CNOT2;MBTPS1;MYH10;CEP350;TSEN34;RGS12;PRPF38A;GOLGA8B;GRAMD1A;ZNF280D;ZNF24;PPP1R12A;PTPN4;TSPAN7;PNRC2;RBM4;TTC14;RBM23;HECTD1;TIAL1;MDM4;SUCO;CHGB;RNF145;MZT2A;KMT2C;AKAP8L;RBBP6;FAM184B;UBE2H;CCDC14;TRIM44;KDM6B;ZNF37A;HDAC3;FAM110B;ZNF326;PHF20L1;NUP107;PLEKHO1;ZMYM4;SEMA3C;CASC3;MARK3;MORC3;IGFBP2;SKIL;OXSR1;ERCC6L2;SLU7;RNF115;PPP1R9A;CRNKL1;TIA1;GOLGB1;RBM5;ERC1;RNASEH2B;LUC7L2;LONP2;SMCR5;PRPF8;ACTL6A;ACBD6;XRN1;PIAS1;KDM5A;CDK13;PRKDC;KANSL1;ZC3H6;PKN2;N4BP2;RICTOR;EIF1AY;SEZ6L;RSRC1;USP48;TCF12;POLK;WAC;XPA;BRD9;DDX3Y;ZNF3;ECI2;PPP4R2;METTL16;VMA21;CCDC59;FTX;PPIL4;CD46;EIF2A;MEF2A;CTR9;KLHL23;ZNF791;CREB1;MIR181A1HG;APPBP2;KIAA2026;RAF1;ADAR;DDX27;CCDC93;RNF168;MED6;PRSS12;TMF1;SNRNP200;BOD1L1;RBM15B;ZNF281;MIA3;WTAP;PCF11;FAM179B;PPP1R12B;KIAA0232;ZNF195;EPB41L3;RNF216;ASXL1;OLFM2;SKIV2L2;SMARCA2;PHF21A;PIBF1;PRR14L;OFD1;TSPYL4;LBR;SHPRH;LRRC58;TCERG1;ADGRB3;ZNF609;POGZ;ZBED5;LSM12;UG0898H09;DCTN4;DIXDC1;CEP97;TRIP11;KIAA1551;ASCL1;ZNF75A;SSR1;XIAP;MLF1;ANKRD17;TFAM", 
"PPP1CB;PTPRS;XIST;NFIA;PPP3CA;INSR;MDM4;SAR1A;SRSF6;TSPYL1;ADNP;CTNNB1;RBP1;IRF2BPL"
)), .Names = c("cluster_A", "cluster_B", "up", "down", "total", 
"up_genes", "down_genes"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Thank you.